# The timestamp reported for this question is wrong

Tags: support, questions, timestamps

If you look at [Kosmonaut's profile](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/449/kosmonaut), you will notice that his only question shows "jan 20 at 0:29" as timestamp.

[image: screenshot]

If you look at the question, [Central Pennsylvanian English speakers: what are the limitations on the "needs washed" construction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5407/when-is-it-ok-to-leave-out-to-be-in-constructions-like-needs-to-be-washed) you will notice that [Lauren Ψ](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/11387/lauren) edited the question on Aug 2 at 17:31, and she didn't answer the question.

Does the timestamp show a different date to avoid the question is bumped on the front page, or is there something more behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire [CHAOS Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character) was given edit privileges, and since they were fixing at least 1000 questions these edits did not bump a question. This means that on a particular question, you can see when it was edited. But, on a user's profile, you can see *who* edited but not when. I think this may relate to how "bumping" works--in this case, the timestamp which bumps a question was not updated.

This phenomenon happened with other members of the CHAOS team. For example, this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/can-i-get-hdr-on-the-4th-gen-ipod-touch-by-upgrading-to-ios-4-1) on Apple was edited in early August, but the [user's page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/189/balexandre#qpage_2-qsort_votes) shows the date on which the question last received a non-CHAOS edit or modification.

Comment: I guess there are two different fields that normally contain the same timestamp, but that in some cases can be set to contain different values.

Comment: @kiam--I would assume so, and CHAOS got some sort of override. (A dev can

Comment: That is what confused me; I have read something about non-bumping edits, but I would have expected the timestamp to be the same in the question, and in the question list.

Comment: @kiam--Sorry, I meant to finish that a dev could back up the timestamp thing. I remember being able to see everything Lauren did if I ran across a top 1000 question--I think because the timestamp goes into revision history